# How to disable jwplayer timeslider

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have jwplayer 6 and i want to disable the jwplayer time slider. Do anyone have any idea that how can i disable its functionality

[image: This is the toolbar snapshot of jwplayer]

Comment: Maybe this post can hel you:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/11631/hide-progress-bar/

Comment: hey that link is for jwplayer 5 i need for jwplayer 6 and i have tried the skiking part `<element name="elapsedBackground" src="divider.png" /><element name="timeSliderCapLeft" src="timeSliderCap.png" /><element name="timeSliderCapRight" src="timeSliderCap.png" /><element name="timeSliderRail" src="timeSliderRail.png" /><element name="timeSliderRailCapLeft" src="timeSliderRailCapLeft.png" /><element name="timeSliderRailCapRight" src="timeSliderRailCapRight.png" />` i have deleted the element from skin and also tried by giving the src path blank but the bar was still there

Comment: Set the "controls" variable to "false", or you would have to do this via a custom skin.

Answer (score 3):

We can Create new skin or edit current custom skin in order to remove time slider.

The below `xml` elements handles the time slider.

```
<element name="timeSliderRail" src="timeSliderRail.png" />
<element name="timeSliderBuffer" src="timeSliderBuffer.png" />
<element name="timeSliderProgress" src="timeSliderProgress.png" />
<element name="timeSliderThumb" src="timeSliderThumb.png" />
```

We can modify them according to our need.